# LoaderManager.initLoader() is not define in the Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-cursorloader

I am learning how to use CursorLoader and i was follwoing a tutorial. in the tutorial, it says, that as long as I am using an activity not a fragment I can initialize the CursorLoader as follows:

```
 LoaderManager.initLoader(1, null, this)
```

but, despite my main class extendes AppCompatActivity, I cant use

```
LoaderManager.initLoader()
```

and it is highlighted with red and the errors says "non-static method cant be referenced from a static context"

and here is a list of the imports used:

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
```

how to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

```
LoaderManager.initLoader()
```

because `initLoader` is an instance method of `LoaderManager`, not a static method, meaning you need an instance of the `LoaderManager` upon that you can call it. To retrieve it you can use `getSupportLoaderManager` or getLoaderManager depending if you want or not the version from the support library. Change

```
LoaderManager.initLoader(1, null, this)
```

with

```
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this)
```